# Bidirectional field value conversion for JAX-RS

Tags: java, jax-rs, cxf

Class Foo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOO")
@XmlRootElement(name = "doo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Fooimplements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "SOME_FIELD")
    private String someField;
```

If someField is "abc", the marshaled XML looks like

```
<foo>
  <someField>abc</someField>
```

Is there any way to annotate a front and back conversion so that, just for the XML marshaling purposes, the Java value "abc" gets converted to "xyz.abc" (by concatenating "xyz." to the beginning of the string) and when the XML is unmarshaled, the value "xyz.abc" is converted to "abc" by removing the first 4 characters? I am using `CXF` if that matters.

Comment: Why don't you have a getter and a setter annotated for this purpose?

Comment: Subsequently, I came upon that option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be achieved with a [`XmlAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html):

```java
public class CustomAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String>{

    @Override
    public String marshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return "xyz." + v;
    }

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return v.replaceFirst("^xyz.", "");
    }
}
```

And use it as following:

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo implements Serializable {

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CustomAdapter.class)
    private String someField;

    ...

 }
```

Alternatively you could use getters and setters for this purpose.